# Paypal MECL Integration

Tags: android

I face a problem while integrating `paypal MECL` to my Android app. I want to make a transaction. Just because of that reason I want to use `paypal_nvp_java_sdk`. My question is about, if I can use `paypal_nvp_java_sdk` in my Android app. If yes, than  I can't import the `xerces.jar` archive due to conflict with `Dalvik`. But if I don't import `xerces.jar` I get an error that can't see the classfile `SAXParser` located in `xerces.jar`.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you downloaded the XCommerce Android library from here - https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-overview ?

Comment: If you mean MECL than yes, however I think that's not enough to send requests to PayPal web server and than implement transaction, that is to send setExpressCheckout request, doExpressCheckout and so forth, that's why I decided to use paypal_nvp_java_sdk

Comment: [Check this Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13493631/1530838


Refer above this link, I hope it will be useful to you